# Ionic 3 Angular 4 Native GoogleMaps Lifecycle Events: What's the REAL order?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm having issues with trying to figure out how to get events to fire in the right order. From what I understand, the order is as follows:

ionViewDidLoad -> ionViewWillEnter -> ionViewDidEnter -> ionViewWillLeave -> ionViewDidLeave

But my question is, where does the constructor go in the lifecycle? And what about `platform.ready`? There are events I have in the constructor that are supposed to load a Google Maps API, but for some reason, every other event seems to fire BEFORE they do, especially when I use `this.platform.ready().then()`.

Here's the relevant code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class CanalGuide {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;
  public types;
  public places;

  constructor(public http: Http, public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, public storage: Storage) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();  
      this.readyTypes();
      this.readyPlaces();
      splashScreen.hide();
      });
    }
```

home.ts

```
   import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 LatLng,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { DetailsPage } from '../details/details';
import { SettingsPage } from '../settings/settings';
import { SettingsService } from '../settings/settings.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('map') element;

  public types;
  public places;
  public landmarks;
  public launches;
  public structures;
  public docks;
  public landmarkArray: any[] = [];
  public launchArray: any[] = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, public http: Http, private googleMaps: GoogleMaps, public storage: Storage) {}
    // Gets json file and prepares to create markers

    ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.storage.get('places').then(
        data => { 
          this.places = data;
          this.initMap(this.places); 
        },
        error => { console.log('Error:', error); }
      );
    }

  }

ionViewDidEnter(){
    if (this.landmarkArray.length < 1)
     return false
    else
      this.storage.get('types').then((data) => { 
       this.types = data;
       }).then(() => {
       this.storage.get('launches').then((data) => {
         this.launches = data;
         console.log(this.launches); // returns Array(0)
         if (this.types.types[3].enabled === false) 
             this.launches.launches.ForEach((launch) => {
               launch.setVisible(false);
             });
         else this.launches.launches.ForEach((launch) => {
               launch.setVisible(true);
             });
          });
       }).then(() => {
         this.storage.get('landmarks').then((data) => {
         this.landmarks = data;
         console.log(this.landmarks); // returns Array(0)
         if (this.types.types[4].enabled === false) 
             this.landmarks.landmarks.ForEach((landmark) => {
               landmark.setVisible(false);
             });
         else this.landmarks.landmarks.ForEach((landmark) => {
               landmark.setVisible(true);
             });
          });
       });
  }
}
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to why my `ionViewDidEnter` is firing before my constructor in `home.ts`, and what I can do to make sure they fire in the right order?

Here's what my logs look like when I run this in `ionic cordova run android`
without the workaround:

```
main.js:338 undefined
main.js:339 undefined
vendor.js:117149 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 5760 ms
main.js:306 []
main.js:307 []
```

Comment: Please simplify a bit the code you're working in this post, as it contains too much information that does not relate to your problem, please add a comment where you are putting your console logs to pin point the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So constructor fires first, before ionViewDidLoad.

Now regarding the platform ready goes in the **app.component** constructor, and this event tells you when you are able to use native functionality, and if is running in a browser it will tell you when the DOM is ready.

[As stated in the official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready)

`platform.ready().then()` is your spot to place GMaps initialization code.

EDIT 1

Now that you've added some code and you are not instantiating a google maps library in the *app.component.ts* but you are only fetching data and storing it, there are a couple of things to fix.

**platform.ready()**

Goes only in the app.component.ts so in home.ts you can just to the `this.storage.get(...)` without wrapping it in `platform.ready().then()`, remove it also in your **ionViewDidEnter**, this is causing a problem and that's why you see things firing in a weird order.

This should give you a stable data flow.

Comment: It's not working. `ionViewDidEnter` is still firing before the constructor, at least according to the console. Are there any workarounds I can use?

Comment: did you removed all platform.ready()? also remember that the storage.get operation resolves a promise, so if you want to check the real order of events, console log right after the function definition (not inside the promise). Anyways, please keep updating your code in the post as you're fixing it.

Comment: All of the platform.ready() except the one in app.component.ts

Comment: The best workaround I could come up with is to add a conditional that stops the code inside `ionViewDidEnter` from running if landmarkArray's length is less than 1.

Comment: keep updating the post, did you solve it or still having problems?

Comment: The workaround did its thing, but I would like to know how to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: When you were debugging this, by chance did you put the console logs outside the promises? for instance right after this line: ```ionViewDidEnter(){```

Comment: I did. They're still going in reverse order without the workaround.